# How to integrate KVC in MVC?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, model-view-controller, key-value-coding

So I have an MVC-application in Cocoa.
There are some custom views, a controller and a model. Of course, the views need to know some stuff, so they get their data from the controller. However, they do not use accessors in the controller, they use KVC with a keypath that calls right through to the model:

```
// In view.m
time = [timeSource valueForKeyPath:@"theModel.currentTime"];
// timeSource is a pseudo-delegate of the view that holds the controller
```

This simplifies things a great deal and technically, the views still don't know the model in person (that is, in pointer). But of course, they access it directly.

Is that a usual (or at least sensible) usage of KVC and MVC?
Or how would you implement this kind of communication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems awfully close to "knowing" the model to me. I don't know how most people do it, but I would be more likely to make properties on the controller. The reason I would avoid that, is that if you change the model, the views break. As I understand it, one of the main strengths of MVC is that if you change the model, you don't have to change the view.

Comment: And then, in the controller you simply pass up the values from the model and override `keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:`, so changes in the model propagate back to the view.